# Making assertions (assert.equal) on two return values in Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

Appreciate any help I can get. I am trying to make an assertion on returned values from a smart contract, and I cannot figure out how to get it to work for a Truffle test. I cannot show all my code in raw format because it is sensitive in nature, but here is what you need from the test:

```
it("should accept a list of obj's and return a string & addr", async () => {
    let cInstance = await Contract.deployed("tester2");
    let cAddress = cInstance.address;
    let returnResult = await cInstance.submission.call("tester2","0xdade","type2","0xwizards",[1,"2","4",4]);
    assert.equal(returnResult.valueOf(), "0xdade", {contractaddress});
```

Here is the function I'm calling on contract:

```
function submission(string memory Id, string memory vId, string memory entryType, string memory hashSig, uint256[] memory list) public returns(string memory, address) {

    return(submittedObjStructs[vId].vId, address(this))
}
```

The contract function returns a string and the contract address, which comes back in an object format.

When I try to use assert.equal(result.valueOf(), string value, address value) it doesn't work and gives me an error that the values don't match for various reasons. And if I try array notation like assert.equal(result[0].valueOf(), string value) I get a vm error and the transaction reverts. Any way I can compare the value of the object that comes back from the function call: {0: '0xdade', 1: '0xcontractaddressexample'}

Answer (score 1):

When none of the returned values is an integer (such as in your case), you can use this:

```
const [x, y] = await cInstance.submission.call(...);
const expected = `0xdade, ${contractaddress}`;
const actual = `${x}, ${y}`;
assert.equal(actual, expected);
```

In other cases (that you may possibly have), for any integer value, add `.toFixed()`.

For example, suppose that the first returned-value is `uint256`, then use this:

```
const actual = `${x.toFixed()}, ${y}`;
```

Comment: thanks for this! When I run this I get "TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable" with a string 0xdade and the contract address

Comment: @colyerfs: On which line are you getting this error?

Comment: one the line reading: const [x, y] = await cInstance.submission.call(...);

Comment: @colyerfs: Well, why is this function not declared `view` (i.e., not constant)??? An **off-chain** call to a non-constant function returns an object which contains transaction-related info, **not** the value or values in the function's return-statement. If this function modifies the state of the blockchain (i.e., this contract or other contracts), then you have no choice. But it doesn't seem to be the case in your code, so you can and should declare this function `view`, and then you'll be able to obtain the returned-value from the off-chain. In addition, calling it will not cost any gas.

Comment: I only posted a subset of the code in the function. It does modify state. It adds the value of the arguments into a struct array. I get a response back in object format {'0': "<value>", '1': '<address>'

Comment: Well in that case you cannot obtain the returned value at the off-chain side, but only at the on-chain side (i.e., when calling this function either from inside your contract or from some other contract). If you want the return values to be available at the off-chain, then you need to generate an event before the return-statement, and then this event' parameters will be included in the transaction object that you receive at the off-chain side.

Comment: That said, you might want to consider splitting your logic into a worker function and a viewer function. In your given example, it seems that the viewer function is not even needed, since the first return-value is available in the state-variable (which if `public` is accessible from the off-chain), and the second return-value is available by definition (it is simply the address of your own contract). Frankly, I don't see any reason why you should return these two values from a function, in particularly a function which requires mining (hence requires gas).

Comment: @colyerfs: See my two comments above.